# Security parameter is not set from environment variable (.env file)

Tags: symfony, security, parameters, configuration, environment-variables

I have following security config for Symfony 5.1

```
firewalls:
        login:
            pattern:  ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path:               /api/login_check
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            security: '%env(bool:API_SECURITY)%'
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

The problem is that it does not set correct boolean value from env var in the line **security: '%env(bool:API_SECURITY)%'** though if it is set directly like **security: false** it works.

I also tried to make intermediate parameter like

```
parameters:
    api.security: '%env(bool:API_SECURITY)%'
```

and then

```
...
security: '%api.security%'
```

but it also does not work though I can get the parameter **api.security** in controller and it is correct

Question is why it does not work?

Short description of the problem: I can not set config flag security.firewalls.api.security if the value comes from .env

Comment: Do any of your env variables (like the database connection string) work?  Which file are the variables set in?  If you are in the dev environment then you would typically copy .env to .env.local

Comment: Yes the database connection is passed thru env var and it works, moreover I can pass '%env(bool:API_SECURITY)%' to common container paraneter and it also works, but I can not pass it to security.firewalls.api.security

Comment: I can only speculate.  The security extension code is very complex and does all kinds of stuff under the hood at compile time.  It is possible that the env variable might not get carried along.  There is actually quite a bit that goes on whenever an env parameter is used regardless of where it is used.  Might try asking on the Symfony slack support channel.  Some of the Symfony developers check there.  You can get there from the Community section in the Symfony docs.

Comment: @Cerad thanks for your advice, I found similar issue on github - https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/37836, posted my case in comments there